# Provider-agnostic parameterized queries

Tags: .net, sql, database

Using DbProviderFactories one can implement provider-agnostic database access.

```
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("ProviderInvariantName");

using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
        ...
    }
}
```

But what if I want to parameterize my query? The format for parameters differs between providers (@param, :param, ?, ...). Is there support for this in the framework? Or do I have to write the code myself, substituting generic parameters in my CommandText for the provider specific form?

Clarification:
For OleDbCommand my CommandText would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumName = ?
```

For SqlCommand my CommandText would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumName = @paramName
```

For OracleCommand my CommandText would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumName = :paramName
```

It's the format of the parameter placeholder in the CommandText I'm talking about, not the DbParameter object.

Comment: use EF with a Linq Provider for your chosen vendor?

Comment: Not an option for the current project.

Comment: There's code inside the Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block that achieves this; I've used it but can't remember how it's implemented,but the source code is available with the download so you could have a look.

Comment: @Rikalous: I checked it out but it looks like there is only API for stored procedures. Also see my comment on Rob A's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rikalous.  [You can use the Enterprise Library Data Access Block.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440726%28v=pandp.60%29.aspx)

The parameters are not specific to the type of db.  For instance, the following will work for both Oracle and Sql.  Where your db and connection are generic as well.

```
Db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ConnString);
Connection = Db.CreateConnection();

var dbCommand = Db.GetStoredProcCommand("sp_xxx");

Db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "lob", DbType.Int32, 200);
Db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "attr", DbType.String, "whatever");
```

The only times I go outside of this approach is for something that isn't yet implemented in my current version such as TVP params or something, but you can simply cast for that.

```
((SqlDatabase)Db).AddInParameter(dbCommand, "location_codes", SqlDbType.Structured, dataTable);
```

Comment: Please see my clarification. Your code is calling a stored procedure, there are no parameter placeholders in the CommandText. Also I checked out the EntLib's Database class and the only interesting method is BuildParameterName. But only SqlDatabase implements it.

Comment: i follow you now, I'll have to take a look later.